# Removing nested dictionary and reordering keys?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I have nested dictionaries and I am trying to remove some of them while reordering the keys after removing.

```
a = {0:[1,2],1:[3,4,5],2:[6,7,8]}`

for i in range(len(a)):
    if len(a[i]) != 3:
        del a[i]
```

The returning dictionary is
`a = {1:[3,4,5],2:[6,7,8]}`

I need to reorder the keys so that I end up with
`a = {0:[3,4,5],1:[6,7,8]}`

Comment: You **do not** have a nested dictionary.

Comment: What is your Python version?

Comment: `a2 = {k-1:v for k,v in a.items() if k >0}`

Comment: @user19077881 I don't think so, there might be a gap with length more than 1 between keys with values of length 3

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi maybe, who knows. We can only respond to the questions asked not speculate about endless 'maybes'

Comment: So, I am working with nested dictionaries but I did not post the full dictionary as the example in the question. The answer below worked.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by sorting the resulted keys after removing keys with `len(value)!=3` and then create a new dictionary with desired keys :

```
a = {0:[1,2],1:[3,4,5],2:[6,7,8]}

for i in range(len(a)):
    if len(a[i]) != 3:
        del a[i]
        
reordered = {i:a[k] for i, k in enumerate(sorted(a.keys()))}
print(reordered)
```

the reordered dictionary will be :

```
{0: [3, 4, 5], 1: [6, 7, 8]}
```

Comment: This worked. I just had to adjust the indexes because the example I posted is not the full dictionary I am working with. Thank you.